# Add a prefix character for each new line using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm looking for a way to add a prefix for each line of text using only CSS. The prefix currently is done with `:before` selector, but I don't know if this can be expanded to multiple lines. For the first line, the prefix is an asterisk `*` and for the following lines a pipe `|`.

Here is a representation of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
* Duo laudem labore interpretaris ne, maiorum qualisque interpretaris mel id. Quo
| enim propriae eu, denique molestie definiebas mel no. Solum integre mandamus his
| ne, sale hendrerit pro ut, ei has libris habemus delicatissimi. Eu eum illud.
```

Same text but different width:

```
* Duo laudem labore interpretaris ne, maiorum 
| qualisque interpretaris mel id. Quo enim
| propriae eu, denique molestie definiebas mel 
| no. Solum integre mandamus his ne, sale
| hendrerit pro ut, ei has libris habemus 
| delicatissimi. Eu eum illud.
```

Notice that the text block **width is variable**, and this is what makes the block number of lines to increment.

Is there any **CSS only** solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have hundreds of thousands of lines, you can use a pseudo element with content of `|\a` (`|` and `\a` line break) just add a large number of them as many as you can.

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}

p:before {
  content: "*";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

p:after {
  content: "|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a";
  white-space: pre;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p>Duo laudem labore interpretaris ne, maiorum qualisque interpretaris mel id. Quo enim propriae eu, denique molestie definiebas mel no. Solum integre mandamus his ne, sale hendrerit pro ut, ei has libris habemus delicatissimi. Eu eum illud.</p>
```

And, of course you can also do it with only one pseudo element.

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}

p:before {
  content: "*\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a|\a";
  white-space: pre;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Duo laudem labore interpretaris ne, maiorum qualisque interpretaris mel id. Quo enim propriae eu, denique molestie definiebas mel no. Solum integre mandamus his ne, sale hendrerit pro ut, ei has libris habemus delicatissimi. Eu eum illud.</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make this visually using gradient. The trick is to consider the `line-height` in order to correctly repeat the pattern for each line then simply adjust the different values to control the size of the line and get close to `|`

```css
.box {
  padding-left:20px;
  font-size:25px;
  line-height:1.2em; /*This is used in the gradient so it should match*/
  background:
   repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,
   transparent 0px, transparent 5px,
   #000 5px,#000 calc(1.2em - 2px),
   transparent calc(1.2em - 2px),transparent 1.2em) 
  4px 0/2px 100% 
  no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> 
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing lorem | Proin pharetra felis eu arcu imperdiet, ac ultricies velit scelerisque. Curabitur mollis purus at dignissim pharetra. Donec in tortor in sapien vulputate pretium at eget risus. Fusce elementum ex ut eleifend accumsan. Aliquam dapibus eleifend malesuada. Vivamus ac mattis sapien, vitae interdum lorem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
</div>
```

To start from the second line simply translate it and you can add the asterix:

```css
.box {
  padding-left:20px;
  font-size:25px;
  line-height:1.2em; /*This is used in the gradient so it should match*/
  background:
   repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,
   transparent 0px, transparent 5px,
   #000 5px,#000 calc(1.2em - 2px),
   transparent calc(1.2em - 2px),transparent 1.2em) 
  4px 1.2em/2px 100% 
  no-repeat;;
}

.box:before {
  content:"*";
  margin-left:-20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin pharetra felis eu arcu imperdiet, ac ultricies velit scelerisque. Curabitur mollis purus at dignissim pharetra. Donec in tortor in sapien vulputate pretium at eget risus. Fusce elementum ex ut eleifend accumsan. Aliquam dapibus eleifend malesuada. Vivamus ac mattis sapien, vitae interdum lorem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
</div>
```

Comment: You make my life difficult. Now I think I need to post in meta: "How to accept multiple answers?" 
Getting serious, I will accept @Stickers answer simply because I've specified the pipe character on the original question. But definitly I will use yours, since it scales better, the `repeat` solution is well thought and avoids the finite solution of repeating pipes.